# Generate skew-normal signal

Tags: gaussian

Is there a simple way to generate a skew-normal shape? Shouldn't be perfect, I just need a rough approximation of it to test peak-detection algorithms.

I tried generating the signal according to the [continuous formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution):

```
y = 2 * gaussian(x) * cumulativeGaussian(skewness * x)
```

But the problem is (I think) - we can't implement infinity. So if I pass left `skewness` - this won't let cumulativeGaussian to ever reach large values - it will stop somewhere in the middle of the cumulative signal.

PS: I found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316314/sampling-from-skew-normal-distribution)/[this example](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/09/30/skew-normal-prng-javascript/), but they talk about distributions of random variables which we can sample from. But I simply need to generate the shape with N points, I don't need a RNG.